# Socket sendto() fails errno 88 and 9

Tags: sockets, udp, errno

I'm trying to run a simple client-server application using UDP (as an exercise), OS Linux Mint 14. 
Client sends a request to the server, when starting, to get a few session parameters, including a timeout in usec.
The client opens a socket and sets a default timeout value, in order non to be blocked indefinetly on recvfrom, then sends a request for those parameters, closes said socket, re-opens a socket setting the new timeout value, and finally asks the user for commands.

The parameters request is dealt with by a subfunction which gets, among other things, a pointer to the client socket, so that the main function will be able to reference the new socket as well, should the new sockfd be a different number.
(Return value is used as a check value, zero or non-zero)

The sequence is:

- client calls for subfunction passing socket pointer
- subfunction sends request
- subfunction gets answer
- subfunction closes old socket
- subfunction opens new socket (socket(), setsockopt, bind()) on the location pointed by the socket pointer (thus replacing the original)

  ### - Problem
- next call to sendto() fails either with errno 9 (bad file number) or with errno 88 (socket operation on non-socket).

Call to function in main: (servaddr is a struct sockaddr_in, hence the cast; sockfd is an int)

```
int checkParameters;
checkParameters=clientrequest(&sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, 0, settings);
```

clientrequest() description:

```
 int clientparameters(int* socketpt, struct sockaddr* remaddr, unsigned int parameters[])

{
unsigned char timeouts = 0;
int received = 0;
socklen_t len;
unsigned char* buff;
if((buff = malloc(MAX_LINE)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    return -1;
}
unsigned char i;







    memset(buff, 0, MAX_LINE);
    if(encode(buff, PARAM) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
        free(buff);
        return -1;
    }



    if(sendto(*socketpt, buff, 1, 0, remaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
        free(buff);
        return -1;
    }

    while(received == 0) {


        len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        if((received = recvfrom(*socketpt, buff, MAX_LINE, 0, remaddr, &len)) < 0) {

            if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                if(timeouts == TIMEOUT_NUM) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Server non found, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
                    free(buff);
                    return -1;
                }
                received = 0;
                timeouts++;


            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d\n errno: %d\n", getpid(), errno);
                free(buff);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}


memcpy(parameters, uncap(buff), sizeof(unsigned int)*3);
/*"uncap" removes user-level protocol header from payload*/

free(buff);



/*Store old socket port + IP address*/
struct sockaddr_in addr;
len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
if(getsockname(*socketpt, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    return -1;
}



if(close(*socketpt) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Errore occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    return -1;
}

/*Opens new socket*/
if(((*socketpt) = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    return -1;
}


/*Set timer*/
struct timeval t;
t.tv_usec = parameters[2]; //Where timer is set

if(setsockopt(*socketpt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &t, sizeof(struct timeval)) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "errno: %d\n win: %u\t loss: %u\t timeout: %u\n\n", errno, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    if(close(*socketpt) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore in close() in clientrequest(), processo %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    }
    return(-1);
}

if(bind(*socketpt, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    if(close(*socketpt) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    }
    return(-1);
}

return 0;
```

}

While once I enter a second request function, it fails at the first sendto() with errno 88.

Here's some sandbox code I tried. It basically follows the same socket(), setsockopt(), bind(), sendto(), close() approach, except "sendto" sends to the same IP/port the socket's bound.

```
int* receptionfd = malloc(4);

struct sockaddr_in addr;
char buff[MAX_LINE];

int n;
unsigned int len;


if((*receptionfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("Error occurred\n");
    free(receptionfd);
    exit(-1);
}

memset((void*)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));


addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
    perror("Errore occurred\n");
    free(receptionfd);
    exit(-1);
}

addr.sin_port = htons(5050);


struct timeval t;
t.tv_usec = 20000;

if(setsockopt(*receptionfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &t, sizeof(struct timeval)) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    if(close(*receptionfd) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
    }
    return(-1);
}



if(bind(*receptionfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    perror("Error occurred\n");
    free(receptionfd);
    exit(-1);
}


if(sendto(*receptionfd, buff, 0, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, first sendto(), errno %d\n", errno);
    free(receptionfd);
    exit(-1);
}
else
    printf("First good\n");

close(*receptionfd);

createsock(receptionfd, addr);

if(sendto(*receptionfd, buff, 0, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, second sendto(), errno %d\n", errno);
    free(receptionfd);
    exit(-1);
}
else {
    printf("Second good\n");
}

close(*receptionfd);
free(receptionfd);
exit(0);
```

createsock() body:

```
void createsock(int* receptionfd, struct sockaddr_in addr) {
if(((*receptionfd) = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
            perror("Error occurred\n");
            free(receptionfd);
            exit(-1);
    }

    memset((void*)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));


    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("Error occurred\n");
        free(receptionfd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    addr.sin_port = htons(5050);



    struct timeval t;
    t.tv_usec = 20000;

    if(setsockopt(*receptionfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &t, sizeof(struct timeval)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
        if(close(*receptionfd) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred, process %d, errno %d\n", getpid(), errno);
        }
    }


    if(bind(*receptionfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error occurred\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

}

(You might notice I copy-pasted a few things from the main sandbox function)
Well, the sandbox always executes "First good, Second good".
I might employ a solution using "select()" and see if it works, but I'd rather understand why this is happening first.

Comment: Please excuse, but the source you show aren't only lots, but also are a mess in terms of format. Propably not only me refuses to read them.

Comment: One - the code formatting a really bad. Please clean it up. To - there is too much code here.  Please reduce it to the bare minimum needed to demonstrate/reproduce the problem.  Third - the `clientparameters()` function you showed has unmatched braces, so it wouldn't even compile let alone run. I stopped looking after that.